# how to change some pats in msgbox

Tags: vba, excel

I wonder it is possible to change some parts in msgbox in the following code in order to receive font color , bold , font name  , strikethrough etc . Is it possible ?

```
Sub test()

    MsgBox " This is Msgbox"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in the MsgBox.

If you want to display text that is formatted, you can create a UserForm.